How to run adb on Termux to control Android itself without USB & Wi-Fi?
When u run the adb devices command in a computer’s terminal, the following steps occur:

The ADB client (CLI) sends the adb devices command to the ADB server via TCP port 5037.
If the ADB server isn’t already running, the ADB client starts the ADB server.
The ADB server communicates with adbd (the daemon running on the Android device) via USB or TCP/IP (for network connections).
adbd processes the command and returns a list of connected devices to the ADB server.
The ADB server formats this information and sends it back to the ADB client.
The ADB client displays the list of connected devices in the terminal.

However, when I run the adb devices command in Termux on the Android device itself, no devices are listed.
I believe this happens because the ADB server doesn’t detect a USB connection when running on the same device (step 3).
I don’t want to use ADB over Wi-Fi; I’m looking for a way to make it work over USB or at least bypass the USB check. Is there some way to fake the USB connection or a loopback method that can help?

Adb over USB requires an USB connection. Therefore you only have the option via adb connect or using adb over Wifi connection.
